# Can we build dynamic hierarchical grid view using AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I newbie to AngularJS. I am using this in one of my project. I need a clarification whether we can implement Hierarchical ng-grid in AngularJS or not

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement hierarchical grid view in ng-grid using GROUPING [ng-grid grouping](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.grouping.grid:grouping)